# force two parameterized types to be different java

Tags: java, generics

I have an `abstract class Processor<T,V>` and two classes that extend it:

```
SimpleProcessor<T> extends Processor<T,T>
```

and

```
Converter<T,V> extends Processor<T,V>
```

The thing is I need to be able to create a list with the various objects and that's why the have the same super class but I also need to be able to tell them apart.

My problem is that I need to be able to force the type parameters to always be a different type(T is a Number V is a String => correct, but if both are String then the compiler will not accept it). Is there a way for that to be done in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. Could you share the code that you've already tried to better understand what's wrong with it and what you want

Comment: Maybe a `Convertor` doesn't satisfy the is a test required for inheritance.  At first glance it seems like you have two separate types.

Comment: abstract class Processor has an abstract method V process(T value);what i am trying to do is enable the user to create a list of transformations for an object to get it from type A to type B and then be able to run through this list of transformations every time i need to convert a value of type A to type B. however i need to know if a certain part of the chain of transformations changes the type of the value i supply that's why i am subclassing Processor. but i want to make it as safe as possible and that's why i need to be able to check that the parameter types are different in Converter.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can't do it in a general way. But you could use distinct super types:

```
Converter<T extends SuperTypeA, V extends SuperTypeB> extends Processor<T, V>
```

I guess that's not  what you're looking for. The next solution would be a runtime test for the types and just throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the types don't match your requirements:

```
public Converter(T t, V v) {
    if (t.getClass() == v.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to ensure this at compile time.

At runtime you have 2 options. One is to pass actual objects and compare concrete classes (which is in an answer already here). The other one requires use of reflection.

Let's say someone declares class as this:

`class MyConverter<T,V> extends Converter<T,V>`

In case someone then instantiates an object like this:

`MyConverter<Number, String> m = new MyConverter<Number, String>();`

or

`Converter<Number, String> m = new Converter<Number, String>();`

It is impossible to write a function that figures out the actual type of converter.
However if a class is declared such as this:

`class MyConverter extends Converter<Number, String>`

it is possible to figure out that it's a Number to String converter using reflection.